Debian OS retain drive APM if I set it with smartctl?
I am working on a Raspberry Pi device which has a Debian Linux installed. Does this OS have any program installed in it by default that keeps the drive APM value I set with smartctl, even after restart or sleep ? I am new to Linux. I know that in Windows there is no such thing. If you set the APM value of a drive, it is lost after a power cycle or return from sleep. But I don't know how it is here...
